Oracle - DBMS Scheduler to run on the second to the last workday of the month excluding weekends and US holidays
Good day,
I am trying to create a DBMS Scheduler that will run at 8:00 A.M. on the second to the last workday of the month excluding weekends and US holidays.
a) If the current date is September 1, 2024, the scheduler should run on September 27, 2024, given that the last workday is on September 30, 2024.
b) If the current date is October 1, 2024, the scheduler should run on October 30, 2024, given that the last workday is on October 31, 2024.
c) If the current date is November 1, 2024, the scheduler should run on November 26, 2024, given that there are two US holidays on November 28 and 29 (Thanksgiving and Day After Thanksgiving), and the last workday is on November 27, 2024.
Currently, here is my configuration for the Scheduler:
BEGIN
    -- List holidays (for visual purposes, I only listed one holiday here)
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'NEW_YEARS_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDATE=0101', comments => 'January 1');

    -- List weekends
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'WEEKEND', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SAT,SUN');

    -- Combine all holidays in one schedule
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'HOLIDAYS', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERSECT=NEW_YEARS_DAY,MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_DAY,PRESIDENT_DAY,MEMORIAL_DAY,JUNETEENTH_DAY,INDEPENDENCE_DAY,THANKSGIVING,DAY_AFTER_THANKSGIVING,CHRISTMAS');

    -- Create schedule to run at 8:00:00 A.M. on the second to last work day of the month excluding weekends and holidays
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
        repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=MONTHLY; BYTIME=080000; BYMONTHDAY=-2; EXCLUDE=HOLIDAYS,WEEKEND;',
        start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2024-10-10 08:00:00.000000000 EST5EDT','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
        comments => 'TEST_SCHEDULER',
        schedule_name  => '"CUSTOM_TEST_SCHEDULER"');
END;
/

To verify the next run date, I am using a PL/SQL block:
DECLARE
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP;
    l_start_date         TIMESTAMP := TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE '2024-09-01');
    l_return_date_after  TIMESTAMP := l_start_date;
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=MONTHLY; BYTIME=080000; BYMONTHDAY=-2; EXCLUDE=HOLIDAYS,WEEKEND;',l_start_date,l_start_date, next_run_date);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Next Run Date: ' || next_run_date);
END;
/

When testing with a date of September 1, 2024, for some reason, the next run date is on October 30, 2024, which is incorrect.
September 1, 2024 Run Date
When testing with a date of October 1, 2024, the next run date is on October 30, 2024, which is correct.
October 1, 2024 Run Date
Lastly, when testing a date of November 1, 2024, the next run date is on December 30, 2024, which is incorrect.
November 1, 2024 Run Date
It seems if the second to the last workday falls on a weekend or a holiday, the next run date transitions to the second to the last workday of the next month.
May I request for feedback if there is an incorrect configuration in the "repeat_interval", or if the way I tested for the next run date is the incorrect way?
Thank you in advance for any feedback.

There is no mechanism to fallback to a calculated date, you should better generate the repeat_interval string yourself based on the year, like 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDATE=20240130,20240228,20240328,20240429,20240530,20240627,20240730,20240829,20240927,20241030,20241127,20241230'
